# Only 3/4 tables were created under Navigator/Schemas in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have created 4 tables total but can only see 3 of them under navigator/schemas in the area where you can write code. Why is that? The 3 tables I can see are all referencing the table that I can't see and all have foreign keys that reference the same column in the table I can't see under navigator/schemas.

Answer (score 0):

`refresh all` under the database, that brings all to the left window, what you have done.

[image]

This you have to manually, because it is nit automatically refreshed, so a `Refresh all** exists at every node in the tree view